# How "one to many table" return only 1 row in each data its get

Tags: mysql

sorry for asking this, so i have 2 table :

table 1 "car"

```
car_id   car_name
   1      toyota
   2      honda
```

table 2 "incident"

```
inc_id   car_id    status    date_status  date_created
   1        1      arrive    2020-07-26    2020-07-26
   2        1      repair    2020-07-27    2020-07-27
   3        1      finish    2020-07-28    2020-07-28
```

i need those data to show like this :

```
car_id     car_name     status_1    date_1    status_2    date_2     status_3    date_3
   1         toyota      arrive   2020-07-26  repair    2020-07-27    finish   2020-07-28
```

i have tried this :

```
SELECT
a.car_id,a.car_name,
(SELECT status,date_status FROM incident WHERE status= 'arrive') AS arrive,
(SELECT status,date_status FROM incident WHERE status= 'repairs') AS repairs,
(SELECT status,date_status FROM incident WHERE status= 'finish') AS finish,
FROM car a
LEFT OUTER JOIN incident b ON a.car_id = b.car_id
WHERE b.date_created BETWEEN '2020-07-27' AND '2020-07-28';
```

but its **return Error Code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row**,

Comment: Generally speaking, you should never have a subquery in a `SELECT` clause. As it is, your query will return meaningless data because you don't have a purposeful `JOIN` in those subqueries (and it will likely run with terrible performance too).

Comment: Did you design this database? Or did someone else? What constraints are in-place to prevent multiple rows in the `incident` table for the same `car_id` but multiple `status` values? Is this table using composite-keys?

Comment: thank a lot @Dai for you comment, what  the best way to do it ?, yep someone else that design this table im just beginner programmer,  but as far as i know its ok to have multiple data in incident table.

Comment: What happens if the same car (by `car_id`) gets involved in multiple incidents (say, 2 years apart)?

Comment: its ok, i will make new columns to flag it, so its will not querying for 2 years apart with the same car_id.

Comment: "i will make new columns to flag it" - that's **not** how you should deal with that possibility. That would mean denormalizing your database. I suggest you read-up on some database-theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Are you sure about `BETWEEN '2020-07-27' AND '2020-07-27'`? Maybe you mean `BETWEEN '2020-07-26' AND '2020-07-28'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must group by car and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.car_id, c.car_name,
      'arrive' status_1,
      max(case when i.status = 'arrive' then date_status end) date_1,      
      'repair' status_2,
      max(case when i.status = 'repair' then date_status end) date_2,
      'finish' status_3,
      max(case when i.status = 'finish' then date_status end) date_3
FROM car c LEFT OUTER JOIN incident i 
ON c.car_id = i.car_id
GROUP BY c.car_id, c.car_name
```

If you add the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE b.date_created BETWEEN '2020-07-27' AND '2020-07-27'
```

any unmatched rows between the tables will be rejected and the join will actually be an `INNER` join.
So if you don't need unmatched rows then fine, but if you do want them then add the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
.....................
FROM car c LEFT OUTER JOIN incident i 
ON c.car_id = i.car_id
AND i.date_created BETWEEN '2020-07-27' AND '2020-07-27'
.....................
```

Comment: You have `GROUP BY c.car_id, c.car_name` in your query. I don't think it's a good idea to `GROUP BY` a non-key (dependent) column (`car_name`) - as I don't trust the DBMS not to perform a relatively expensive string-comparison for each row.

Comment: *I don't think it's a good idea* it is not only a good idea, but it is also the proper way to do it.

Comment: "The proper way to do it" - according to whom? (I am being sincere, I hope I don't come across as being rude) - but I've never seen that advice in any of the manuals from the major RDMBS vendors.

Comment: *I don't think it's a good idea* according to whom?

Comment: Me, I used the "I" pronoun, and I stated that I think it's a bad idea because there's no guarantee that the execution-plan for the query wouldn't involve an unnecessary string comparison.

Comment: So this is what you stated. Any proof about that?

Comment: I can't prove a negative - but I can point to the ISO SQL-92 specifications (and later) - and that specification does not require implementations to follow/track the uniqueness of columns used in a `GROUP BY` clause, which is why I said it's _possible_ for a suboptimal execution plan to be derived from your query.

Comment: *I can't prove* and *possible*... are the poorest arguments.

Comment: I accept that I didn't make the strongest argument, but **you** said "it is the proper way to do it" - so please, tell me who is saying that your approach is "proper" and on what authority or basis? I want to be *less wrong* and I want to post better answers for other questions in future - I'd love to incorporate the advice I'm seeing in your post, but I can't without a solid source or citation for the claim you're making - especially when it's in opposition to my intution and knowledge of the ISO SQL spec.

Comment: thank guys for you comment and help, @Dai query work perfectly, i change the `GROUP BY` to `BETWEEN date_created`, thank again :)

Comment: @TrayScott If it was my query that worked perfectly, please accept my answer, not this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT
    c.car_id,
    c.car_name,
    i.first_arrived,
    i.first_repairs,
    i.first_finish
FROM
    car AS c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            car_id
            MIN( CASE WHEN status = 'arrive'  THEN date_status END ) AS first_arrived,
            MIN( CASE WHEN status = 'repairs' THEN date_status END ) AS first_repairs,
            MIN( CASE WHEN status = 'finish'  THEN date_status END ) AS first_finish
        FROM
            incident
        GROUP BY
            car_id
    ) AS i ON c.car_id = i.car_id
```

However it isn't possible to produce your original desired columnset of `status_1, date_1,    status_2, date_2, status_3, date_3` with the information you've given me because there could be many other distinct (and duplicate!) `status` values - and data should always be row-based, not column-based. Any `UNPIVOT` logic should be in your application code, not SQL.

Comment: This does not return the expected results.

Comment: @forpas My query returns the same results as the OP's example query, and I explained that it isn't possible to return a meaningfully-correct "unpivoted" result (for the `status_1`, `status_2`, etc) query because the OP hasn't provided the necessary details (e.g. what if there are other status values? What is the ordering? etc).

Comment: So where are the columns status_1, status_2 and status_3?

Comment: @forpas I've explained **twice** (in my answer post, and again in my comment reply) why it isn't possible to provide a meaningful answer that includes `status_1`, `status_2`, etc. What part about my explanation don't you accept?

Comment: @forpas You still haven't answered my question about where your "it is the proper way to do it" claim comes from, btw.

Comment: Why should I? Did you prove what you said in your 1st comment? Why did you even post it? Just to start a conversation? Comments are meant to ask and/or provide additional clarifications or to point at minor or major errors/details. You just made ana argument without any proof. For me this is not going anywhere.

Comment: "Did you prove what you said in your 1st comment?" - Yes, I did. I made the claim about the ISO SQL spec that you can verify is true by reading the spec. It was **you** who made an explicit claim that including dependent attributes in a `GROUP BY` is the "proper" way but **you** didn't cite a source for that. I cited a source for my claim (i.e. the ISO SQL spec) - what's your citation?

Comment: @forpas "Comments are meant to ask and/or provide additional clarifications" - yes. I am seeking clarification: Please clarify how including dependent attributes in a `GROUP BY` is "proper". How is it anything besides a syntactical (i.e. ergonomical) improvement over `JOIN` for dependent attributes?